# Converting any file into binary in java

Tags: java, file, binary

Anyone know how can I read any file in binary using Java? I want to be able to read any image, document, pdf etc as a stream of binary digits. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you want [FileInputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html)! You may find the [Basic I/O tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/) useful too.

Answer (score 1):

use FileInputStream

> FileInputStream is meant for reading streams of raw bytes such as image data. For reading streams of characters, consider using FileReader.